# Casting an Integer to a Single, preserving bit representation

Tags: vb.net, casting

Is there a fast way in VB.NET to take a 32-bit int and cast to a 32-bit float while preserving the underlying bit structure?  BitConverter will do this, but I'd like to cast it directly without involving byte arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by "preserving the underlying bit structure" and why do you need it?

Comment: I'm using [bit twiddling](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) to improve performance in a bottleneck and I'm looking for the absolute fastest bit hack for a few functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn, how could I possibly forget about The C-style Union?

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
Public Structure IntFloatUnion
    <Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)> Public i As Integer
    <Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)> Public f As Single
End Structure


Sub Main()
    Dim u As IntFloatUnion

    u.i = 42
    Console.WriteLine(u.f)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

---

<s>Well, how about writing a helper function in C# similar to one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479705/reinterpret-cast-in-c):</s>

```cs
public static class FancyConverter
{
    public static unsafe float FloatFromBytes(int i)
    {
        return *((float*)(void*)(&i));
    }
}
```

This can be compiled to a separate dll and referenced from the VB project.