# Visual Basic.Net Converting a Long to a Ulong

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, long-integer

I am having issues using **VB.Net** trying to convert a `Long` to a `ULong.`
I have tried many combinations and keep getting overflow errors.
I have a signed value of -2147483648, I know it will have a `Ulong` of 2151196588 once converted.

However I want to do this in a programmatic fashion because I am parsing values that can be negative and positive, but when the numbers are negative, they need to have the proper `ulong` value.
Note: Absolute values wont work, it needs to be a `ulong` for a true value.
Thank you.

Comment: `I have tried many combinations and keep getting overflow errors.`  It would probably be helpful to list *what* you have tried so others don't end up suggesting something you've already done.

Comment: Your expected value cannot be correct. Since the most significant bit is set in your negative number, the converted number must be multitudes larger than the absolute value of it. The `ULong` will contain `2^64 - 2147483648 = 18446744071562067968`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean `reinterpret_cast<ulong>(long)`, then use the [same technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6474003/11683):

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
Public Structure LongULongUnion
    <Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)> Public l As Long
    <Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)> Public ul As ULong
End Structure


Sub Main()
    Dim u As LongULongUnion

    u.l =  -2147483648L
    Console.WriteLine(u.ul)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

But that gives `18446744071562067968` when converted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the BitConverter class:

```
Dim a As Int64 = -2147483648
Dim b = BitConverter.ToUInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(a), 0)
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString) ' outputs: 18446744071562067968
```

Are you sure your intended value of 2151196588 is correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to convert *any* Long to ULong:

```
Dim x As Long = -2147483648
Dim y As ULong = Not (CType((Not x), ULong)) ' = 18446744071562067968
```

I'm a C# programmer, so please correct me if I converted it to VB.NET incorrectly. My C# code was:

```
long x = -2147483648;
ulong y = ~((ulong)~x); // = 18446744071562067968
```

Basically you take the complement of the negative value, which is always a positive value. You can then safely cast it to ULong. Take the complement again and you have the same bit pattern cast to ULong.

Comment: That doesn't actually work for positive `Long`s, only for negative ones. So it's not *any* long, its *any negative* Long.

Comment: Let me try again, because I tested it with the boundaries of Long and zero and they all worked...

Comment: @GSerg Zero and all positive values work, in as far that they remain the same value, because they have the same bit pattern as before... why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: It works in C#, but not VB. VB will instead throw `OverflowException` upon trying to `CType` a now-negative number to `ULong`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I took a deeper look into the code that this developer was using. He is using binary reader to read ctree index and getting the offsets. The problem seems to be that he is off one byte occasionally which will render -2147483648 but if you move the byte once more it will have a value of 2151196588. I am not sure why this happens as ctree has the same pattern through the entire index records. I am not sure why he gets out of alignment and magically he gets back aligned on the next record... but this misalignment happens at random times.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are converting your value to positive BEFORE you convert it to ulong, negatives are not in a ulong's value scope.

```
long: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
ulong: 0 to 18446744073709551615
```