# Casting from double to long and back to double

Tags: c#

Given

```
public long A()
{
    double a = 3.1415296;
    return ??
}

double b = (??) A();
```

is it possible cast, but not convert, `a` such that it is hidden in a long?

Comment: What the Hell are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I guess you're asking for the equivalent of `reinterpret_cast` in C#. If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19497765/2065121) may be helpful.

Comment: @JeanHominal My data is provided in longs, but are really doubles and longs mixed together. Therefore it could be convenient to process the double data in a way, but hide them in a long such that processing could always return long.

Comment: @And when you receive a long... How do you know whether it is really a `long` or a converted `double`? That looks like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. Please ask about your actual problem with your data.

Comment: @JeanHominal I define the return type. I tell the system give me the value of X as a double, the value of Y as a long, and the system returns an int[] no matter what. However inside the int[] the data is correct if interpreted as double and long.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do it using the bit converter:

```
public long A()
{
    double a = 3.1415296;
    return BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(a);
}
```

([method documentation can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: It works, though, isn't this creating a new long based on `a` so it really isn't a cast?

Comment: @lejon This is not a cast, it is a re-interpretation of the same bits as a `long` value. Since `long` is a value type, any time you return it, C# makes a copy. Your program with a cast made a copy, too - there is no "in place re-interpretation" (it's also not applicable, because `a` being returned is local).

Comment: Suppose `a` was passed in the method. Could it then be re-interpreted?

Comment: @lejon Since re-interpreting is telling the compiler that a memory block where a piece of data is stored should have a different type, re-interpretation of a variable is not possible inside a method: you would have to pass a reference to a `double` and a reference to a `long`, both pointing to the same location. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put the actual represenation of the `double` in a `long` variable, and get it back:

```
double a = 3.1415296;

long b = BitConverter.ToInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(a), 0);

double c = BitConverter.ToDouble(BitConverter.GetBytes(b), 0);
```

In the same way you could for example put a `singe` in an `int`.