# Entity Framework two tables with identical objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, downcast

I have two tables that have identical properties, for example:

```
DbSet<Person> Students;
DbSet<Person> Teachers;
```

However Entity Framework does not allow the same class to be used for different tables.

So, instead I use:

```
DbSet<Student> Students;
DbSet<Teacher> Teachers;

public class Student : Person { }
public class Teacher : Person { }
```

However if I retrieve from a third party, a large set of data as

```
List<Person> data;
```

I am unable to do

```
Students.Add(data) <== compile time error unable to convert
```

nor

```
foreach (var item in data)
    Students.Add((Student)item); <== runtime error unable to cast
```

Any suggestions on a good way to handle this?

Note: this is a simplistic example it is actually used for large quantities of stock price bars and performance is a big issue and I don't necessarily want to be instantiating many, many copies of an object if I can help it.

Comment: yeah I'm not surprised this doesn't work.  Even with the same properties, it won't know that it can convert Person to Student.  One idea is to serialize Person to a json string, and then de-serialize it as a Student.  It would take two lines of code, and should be fast,

Comment: You could make a new interface, `IPerson`, and have `Student`, `Teacher`, and `Person` all implement `IPerson`.  Then change your collection to a `List<IPerson>`.

Comment: Also, you can not add a collection to another collection with the `Add` method.  `Add` expects a single element.  What you want is the `AddRange` method.

Comment: You could use `ReinterpretCast` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078952/2557128) but it is a type safety violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need more details on how you create the `List<Person>` for a completely valid answer, but if you create it by adding `Student` and `Teacher` objects, then you should be able to cast the ones that actually *are* `Student`s at runtime:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Student());
people.Add(new Teacher());
foreach(Student student in people.OfType<Student>())
{
    Students.Add(student);
}
```

I would also make `Person` `abstract` so you are forced to use one of the concrete types.