# how to get a `byte[]` from some bytes of another array without copying

Tags: c#, byte

I have a `ushort[]` that is, for example, Length 7,

```cs
var ushorts = new ushort[7] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

that is 14 contiguous bytes in memory.

```
01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00
```

I need a `byte[]` from somewhere in the middle of those 14 bytes, without copying the data.

Here is an example of doing it in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned char byte;

int main() {
    ushort* ushorts = new ushort[7] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    byte* bytes = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&(ushorts[2]));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        std::cout << (int)bytes[i] << ' ';
    }
    // stdout: 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0

    std::cout << std::endl;
    delete ushorts;
    return 0;
}
```

In C#, how can I get a `byte[]` from an arbitrary place in a `ushort[]` without copying the data?

Comment: I tried messing with this impl of reinterpret_cast for C# https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078952/3261120 but I don't know how to get the middle of an array, and as the author points out, it doesn't work for things of different sizes.

Comment: Strictly as a `byte[]`, you can't, but you can do it with spans. Research `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`.

Comment: You said "Without copying the data".  Can you clarify whether you mean "without copying *any* of the data" or "without copying *all* of the data"?  If you are ok avoiding a copy of the entire array, but copying the data of interest from the middle, then `Buffer.BlockCopy`.

Comment: without copying any of the data, in the same way that the C++ example `bytes` doesn't have a copy of the data

Comment: How do you intend to use it? If you're looking at it directly yourself (as your example loop does), spans will work great. If you need to pass it to some method that expects an array, you'll need to make a copy. The BCL has been updated with overloads that take spans in addition to those that take arrays.  Third-party libraries will be hit and miss. Please expand on how you would use this window into the original array, as this will indicate whether a copy-free solution is possible.

Comment: I might be able to use a `Span<byte>`, but I looked into `Span` a little bit and didn't see a way to get the bytes of the underlying data structures. I might accept an answer to showed how to do it.

Comment: `Span<T>` defines the `[]` operator (in C++ terms, in C# terms, is't the indexer property) so normal indexing is possible in a `for` loop. It also supports `IEnumerable<T>` so you can use `foreach`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw all of that. But I don't know how to get the individual bytes for data structures that are more than one byte. Can you translate the C++ example so that `bytes` is a `Span<byte>` and it gives the same output?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3atcRT

Comment: *"data structures that are more than one byte"* - Well, that's a new question. This question is too minimal to address that. What are you trying to deserialize?

Comment: `MemoryMarshal.Cast` is what I was missing. I would have guessed that it kept the same number of elements, instead of the same number of bytes.

Comment: `ushort` is a data structure that is more than one byte. It just happens to also be a primitive. It would be nice if `MemoryMarshal.Cast` worked the same way for non-primitives, but luckily it'll work for my case.

Comment: You can use `struct`s for that. With the right layout, you can reinterpret a series of bytes as a struct instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get an *array* of the middle, but you can get a *span* (`Span<byte>` or `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`):

```cs
ushort[] original = ...
var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(original); // zero-copy
var slice = bytes.Slice(4, 7); // zero copy
```

Watch out for CPU-endianness when dealing with `ushort` to `byte` operations (this applies in the C/C++ version equally).

Note that there is also `MemoryMarshal.Cast` for scenarios that don't involve bytes - for example, going from a `Span<int>` to a `Span<Vector<int>>` for SIMD purposes.