# C# multiple arrays with the same memory

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

Is it possible in C# to have multiple arrays at the same memory location with the arrays having different types?
I have a large float array, and I need to convert it to a byte array in as short a time as possible.
My Idea was to have a byte array that points to the beginning of the float array, so that if I change the float array the byte array automatically changes as well, but I have not yet found a solution to do so.
Is that even possible in C# or do I have to find another way?

I need the byte array to be an actual array of type "byte[]", because I have to call a function in a library I have no access to.

Comment: [reinterpret_cast in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/479705/92546)? (Result of a search for `c# reinterpret array`.)

Comment: @HABO The type I get there is byte* and not byte[], but I need it to be byte[] to call a function

Comment: How much memory are you talking about? How often will this be done? Computers are ridiculously fast at simple tasks like copying memory. It is fairly common that people spend time "optimizing" the wrong thing. So you should *measure* before doing any kind of optimizations, that way you know you have actually made a meaningful improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that with *actual arrays* (at least of different element sizes in memory) - but if you're happy to use that with `Span<T>` instead, then [`MemoryMarshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal) could be what you're looking for. (And you can still use an array as the underlying storage.)

For example:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Span<float> floats = new float[3];
Span<byte> bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(floats);

Console.WriteLine(bytes[0]); // 0
floats[0] = 1.234f;
Console.WriteLine(bytes[0]); // 182
bytes[0] = 200;
Console.WriteLine(floats[0]); // 1.2340021
```

Or to go in the opposite direction, keeping a `byte[]` variable but using a `Span<float>` as a sort of float-oriented view over the byte array:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
Span<float> floats = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, float>(bytes);

Console.WriteLine(bytes[0]); // 0
floats[0] = 1.234f;
Console.WriteLine(bytes[0]); // 182
bytes[0] = 200;
Console.WriteLine(floats[0]); // 1.2340021
```

Comment: I need the byte values to be an array, because I call a function of a library I can't alter

Comment: @Plat00n: What about the other way round: could you create a `byte[]` and then use a `Span<float>`? Because that would work too... (Give more detail and I'll edit an example in there...)

Comment: I think that could work. How do I convert the bytes to floats? I don't see a AsFloats() function

Comment: @Plat00n: See my edit, which contains a complete example.

Comment: Is it possible to make the floats span a class variable, or do I have to create it every time I want to use it in a function? (I can't pass it to the function I need to use)

Comment: @Plat00n: No, you can't store a `Span` in a class field or a regular struct field, as they're ref struct types. However, the span itself is "cheap" to create - it's not like it's copying data or anything.

Comment: IS there a way to create the Span outside a Prallel.For loop and access it inside? The compiler says I can't use a Span inside a lambda expression

Comment: @Plat00n: Please don't use comments to ask additional questions like this. Post a new question with a concrete example etc.