# How to convert c++ union type into c# code?

Tags: c#, c++, unions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ union in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126781/c-union-in-c-sharp)

```
#define AVEC3(T)    union { T v3[3]; struct { T x,y,z; }; }
#define AMAT3x3(T)  union { \
                    T v9[9], m3x3[3][3]; \
                    struct { T v3x[3], v3y[3], v3z[3]; }; \
                    struct { AVec3<T> vecx, vecy, vecz; }; \
                    struct { AVec3<T> right, up, back; }; \
                    struct { T xx, xy, xz, yx, yy, yz, zx, zy, zz; }; \
```

I have no idea how to convert the code from above(c++) into c# version. Assume T is double type.

Answer (score 8):

C# doesn't have a similar notion to `union`, but there is a trick to obtain the same functionality see more here where the `FieldOffset` attribute is used: [C# equivalent to C "union"? from MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/60150e7b-665a-49a2-8e2e-2097986142f3/)

From the MSDN post (simplified a bit):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ByteArray {
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public byte Byte1;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public int Int1;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public int Int2;
}
```

Comment: I have go through it but it doesn't show the example for array inside a struct.