# Primitives, generics and overloading - can an interface method return type be defined as some set of structs and primitives?

Tags: c#

I have components defined by this interface:

```
    public interface IAgentObservation<T>
    {
        T GetObervation();
    }
```

They are injected into a class which has a series of protected overloaded methods, such as:

```
protected void AddVectorObs(bool observation);
protected void AddVectorObs(Quaternion observation);
protected void AddVectorObs(bool observation);
protected void AddVectorObs(IEnumerable<float> observation);
```

I'd like to be able to inject all the components into a single list so that they can be iterated over calling `AddVectorObs(component.GetObservation)` on each, however obviously T needs a 'where' clause, except the 'where' class isn't a shared interface but rather a set of specific and disperate types.

I've worked around this for now using pattern matching, as so:

```
private void AddVectorObsForType<T>(T test)
        {
            switch (test)
            {
                case float f:
                    AddVectorObs(f);
                    break;
                case int i:
                    AddVectorObs(i);
                    break;
                case Vector3 v3:
                    AddVectorObs(v3);
                    break;
                case Vector2 v2:
                    AddVectorObs(v2);
                    break;
                case IEnumerable<float> ef:
                    AddVectorObs(ef);
                    break;
                case Quaternion q:
                    AddVectorObs(q);
                    break;
                case bool b:
                    AddVectorObs(b);
                    break;
                case ValueTuple<int,int> t:
                    AddVectorObs(t.Item1, t.Item2);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unsupported observation vector type: " + typeof(T));
```

But this feels far from ideal.

Comment: Can you show us where the vectors are stored? I don't understand how you're storing disparate types in a single list right now.

Comment: `AddVectorObsForType(object test)` makes sense. A generic version doesn't: If `T` is known at compile time, just let the compiler pick the appropriate overload of `AddVectorObs()`.

Comment: By "some set of structs and primitives", are you saying you want to return a union, or [some unholy C# equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126807/424129)? Can you show pseudocode illustrating what you'd like to do with that, if you could?

Comment: Each type is converted to a number of floats and added to a `List<float>` (used by a machine learning agent).

I could just have my interface method return a float array and add them directly but I'd rather re-use the object -> float[] conversion methods already existing